# Problema con certificado de seguridad IIS

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, windows-server-2012, tls

Tengo una api REST con .net CORE 3.1, cuando la ejecuto como proyecto funciona correctamente.
La publiqué hace unos días y funcionó correctamente en un servidor IIS.
Luego le realicé algunos cambios y ya no funciona, cuando actualicé la api, sólo le agregué una nueva clase para mapear un objeto, no interferí con el web.config ni ninguna otra configuración.

aquí el web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <modules>
        <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
      </modules>
      <handlers>
        <remove name="WebDAV" />
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\API.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Aquí anexo mi launchSettings.json:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://dominio.com.mx",
      "sslPort": 44349
    }
  },
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "api/Conductores",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production"
      }
    },
    "REST_API": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "api/Conductores",
      "applicationUrl": "http://dominio.com.mx/",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production"
      }
    },
    "TESTING": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "api/Conductores",
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:80/",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Cuando la publico en mi servidor local IIS funciona pero, a través de postman, me devuelve este warning:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el mensaje:
**Warning: Unable to verify the first certificate**

Cuando la publico en un servidor IIS remoto, me manda el siguiente mensaje:

**Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames.**

A que se podría deber este error?

Ya intenté habilitar TLS y no funcionó:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que era añadir las claves del TLS.

Comment: Hola! Por favor, evita referenciar recursos externos e incluye en tu pregunta, los cambios que hiciste en configuración para intentar habilitar TLS en tu servidor. El error hace referencia a que estás usando un certificado para un dominio dado (digamos, _algunacosa.com_) y le estás intentando llegar por otrodominio.com (o por la IP). Como el certificado no cubre nada aparte de _algunacosa.com_, te dice que hay un certificado pero no corresponde al recurso (la URL) que le estás pidiendo.

Comment: También yo creo que el problema no debería ser en tu aplicación, mas bien en el dominio, el iis es el que provee el certificado a el navegador, y debe estar generado a otro dominio que no es con el que se genero

Comment: Sí, pero, está raro que con una versión anterior si funciona sólo es cuando genero otro publicado. Por eso anexé los archivos de configuración.

Comment: pero publicaste otra versión sobre el mismo dominio, mismo iis, todo igual?

Comment: Sí, lo único que hice fue agregar un modelo, y luego publicar, en el mismo dominio, mismo IIS, no cambié nada de la configuración.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya pude resolver el problema pero, no era error con el certificado de seguridad, ignoro porque me arrojo ese error. El detalle fue que mi route estaba mal escrito.

estaba así

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
```

cuando debía estar así

```
[Route("[controller]")]
```

por eso al entrar al sitio **https//:dominio/api/Datos** no lo encontraba ya que lo detectaba de esta manera **https//:dominio/api/api/Datos**. El error en realidad era un 404 pero, ignoro porque lo asocio con un error de certificado.

Comment: Interesante. Posiblemente estaba cargando algún recurso (para manejo del error) por defecto por fuera de donde estan los recursos del dominio o algo similar.